# Finding the values of a constant given a second differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My question asks for the value of r in $$y^{\prime\prime}-8y^\prime+16y=0$$ when $y=xe^{rx}$. I am able to separate this into two factors so the equation looks like $(xr^2+2r-8xr+16x-8)(e^{rx})=0$ but am unsure how to proceed further so as to find values for r.

Comment: Why use $y=xe^{rx}$? Start with $y=e^{rx}$, this gives $y'=re^{rx},y''=r^2 e^{rx}$. The rest should be easy.

Comment: The equation you have should be valid for any $x$. In particular, for $x=0$.

Comment: @AwnonBhowmik Why use $y=xe^{rx}$? Because that’s what the assignment said to do, I should think.

Comment: @GLG How would this be valid for any x? e^rx=0 DNE, so we have to look at the other sequence to make it equal to zero, and it is apparent to see that not every x would work.

Comment: @Cosmic $y(x) = xe^{rx}$. Then, $y''(x)-8y'(x)+16y(x) = 0$ says that you should get zero no matter what $x$ you plug in. In particular, $y''(0)-8y'(0)+16y(0) = 0$. Plugging $x=0$ into $(xr^2+2r-8xr+16x-8)e^{rx} = 0$ will give you the value for $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting $y=xe^{rx}$ and its derivatives into the equation $y''-8y'+16y=0$ we get $$(2r-8)e^{rx}+(r^2-8r+16)xe^{rx}=0.$$
Since the functions $e^{rx}$ and $xe^{rx}$ are linearly independent, we have $$2r-8=0,\,r^2-8r+16=0,$$
which gives $r=4$.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: you are welcome good luck

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already found  $$(xr^2+2r-8xr+16x-8)(e^{rx})=0$$ just let $$x=0$$ and you get $$r=4.$$

Comment: You could have just edited your old answer instead of posting a second one. I suggest deleting one of them.